# Clear glide cache across all activites?

Tags: android, caching, android-imageview, android-glide

I have the user's profile pic across multiple activities in my app. Once, they change their profile image, I want to make sure that all my Glide instance's cache are cleared. That way when they navigate around the app, they can see their updated profile pic.

Currently I'm using this method: `Glide.get(activity).clearDiskCache();` and that only clears the Glide cache for that activity and not across my app.

Hope someone has a quick solution, where I don't need to call the .signature() function for each glide instance in each of my activites. Or clear each glide cache in each activity.

Comment: `Glide`'s cache is shared between all activities. Your problem was that your `ImageView` not show updated profile picture. You can subclass `ImageView` and broadcast an event to notify your `ImageView` to update it own content or notify your `Activity/Fragment` to update content of `ImageView`.

Comment: yeah i was afraid i might have to do individual updates across all my activities :/

Comment: Sub class `ImageView` will help

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
Glide.get(context).clearMemory();
```

**OR**

```
Glide.get(context).clearDiskCache();
```

**Note:** clearMemory() must be called on the main thread. clearDiskCache() must be called on a background thread. You can't call both at once on the same thread.

Answer (score 2):

I went through this whole windmill trying Signatures and clearing caches, and to be honest - none of those options work particularly well and they're usually slow.

Glide's first recommended solution is bar far superior, although it can sometimes take a bit more time to rework your code. I eventually lost my marbles and made the necessary changes to my code. It was well worth it.

**Solution:** Change the image name of the image when the user uploads a new image. Get the file name and use that. Once the image URL has changed, Glide understands you have changed the image and will update the Cache accordingly.